# Using GPS with DOZE in Android 8

Tags: gps, doze

I have an app which runs a background service to monitor GPS location and compare it to a list of locations. When it finds a match, it sends a broadcast to trigger a foreground activity which then displays information about the location. The GPS tracking uses the GPS capability in Google Play Services, and needs to get an update about every 20 seconds.

Most of the time, the user is unaware of the app and can do other stuff. The foreground UI will probably not be triggered more often then every 2 minutes, and it could be as long as 20 minutes or more. The rest of the time, it is important that the app can continue to get GPS locations without interrupting whatever else the user is doing.

I am trying to understand the impact of the new Doze and Standby features in Android 8. It looks to me from reading the latest docs that it will no longer work, and the background service will not get its updates (or will only get a few every hour, which is useless). Can anyone tell me if this is right?

They appear to say that I should use a foreground service, but elsewhere they say that foreground services should only be used where some user interaction is needed. Seems like catch 22. Is a foreground service ok for something like this?

The docs also refer to whitelisting, but I'm not clear what this really does. Can I whitelist my app to make it continue to work?

Can anyone help a confused amateur developer?

Chris S

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I now understand it a little better. I have not found any way do this using a background service. I tried asking for REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission in the manifest, but it still didn't work - the GPS tracking stops after a few minutes. To do what I want, I have had to convert the tracking to a foreground service - that works OK.